# The input was not a valid SOAP message because the following header is missing

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I am getting below message,

The input was not a valid SOAP message because the following header is missing

Able to get the response from SOAP UI. But I am not able to get the response back from my code.

here is the code

```
post.setRequestHeader(
        "Content-type", "text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1");
RequestEntity entity;
HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
httpclient.getParams().setSoTimeout(10000);
entity = new StringRequestEntity(getReceiveTranscactionRequest(), "text/xml",
        "ISO-8859-1");
post.setRequestEntity(entity);
```

I am getting Hard coded request in getReceiveTranscactionRequest() method

Adding XML Request  -> http://www.teleflora.com/webservices/ReceiveTransactionsuuid:e11c3a90-5929-46d9-85dc-f75df736e740urn:TelefloraWebServices/Gatewayhttp://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/03/addressing/role/anonymous2009-10-01T21:53:36Z43357100XTYNHW81NzUzNzVhNDMtZDhlYS04NTZlLThkMDMtODExNGFjOTk5NmMy 2009-10-01T21:53:36Z

Comment: whats the  SOAP request xml when you fire it through SOAP UI ?

Comment: doesnt make any sense .. can you please elaborate your XML request